# What should I use as a login and password while connecting to the bitcoin daemon

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm creating a pool, right now I'm trying to connect to bitcoin daemon, it responses with error "401", "HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized".

What should I enter in "login" and "password" fields?

Btw: should I ask here on maybe on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/? It's the same company, isn't it?

Comment: Try bitcoi.stackexchange.com as this is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a bitcoin.conf file with the credentials in there? You need to make one and put it in ~/.bitcoin/

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to answer my own question - the problem was, that bitcoind does *something* in during the first ~10 seconds upon startup. During this time it does not respond to any queries. That *something* is not downloading the blockchain because it already did this before. Ps. I can't upvote I have too low reputation.